# Removing of Joker's face

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, the-joker

In which comic does this happen, exactly? I just bought "Death of the Family" and apparently it happens a year before it.
 Does it happen during the "Court of Owls" arc? It is even earlier?

http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_Death_of_the_Family_(Collected)

[image]

Comment: Can you possibly give more details to the scene

Comment: That's the thing. The problem is that I don't know the scene. I just know that at certain point Joker make someone removes his face, and now("Death of the family" New 52) he is using it as a mask.

Comment: Ok that gives some more to work off thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Detective Comics Vol 2 1 (November 2011)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_2_1)*

[image: Cover of Detective Comics Vol 2 1 - (November 2011)]

> Batman leaves the Joker at Arkham Asylum, where Dr. Jeremiah Arkham declares that he will take the clown on as a patient. After Joker is left alone, a man called Dollmaker enters the room. As it turns out, the Joker had planned to be caught and taken to Arkham for the sole purpose of an audience with this man. Joker tells Dollmaker that he killed his son earlier because he insists on only the father's expertise.
>
> According to their plan, the Dollmaker cuts the skin from the Joker's face, leaving the madman ecstatic with the pain. Tonight, they will celebrate their rebirth.

The wiki leaves out that the face was nailed onto the wall as a sign.

[image: Joker's Face, pinned to the wall]

I found the issue by looking at the Wikipedia article for *Death in the Family*, which had [a footnote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_the_Family#CITEREFSalvadorNovember_2011) indicating where the face was cut off. Although, I'll admit that I started with a Google search, first for a mistaken memory of hearing that Hush cut it off, but that included a reference to the Wikipedia article for *Death in the Family* and also [this discussion board](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/batman-286/why-did-joker-let-his-face-get-cut-off-700935/) which includes a panel of Batman discussing that Joker did it voluntarily (not certain what issue this is).

[image: Batman and Robin (Damian) discussing Joker getting his face cut off by the Dollmaker]

Lastly, there's a fairly in-depth discussion of the story arc [here](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/death-of-the-family/4045-56853/).

Comment: yes, it totally is. My problem was that I was only looking into Batman comics, and no into Detective Comics ones. Thanks for the answer. Do you know if that issue is compile in any collection  or something?

Comment: *The Joker: A Celebration of 75 Years* (http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/The_Joker:_A_Celebration_of_75_Years)

Comment: @Xhark Also it is in Batman Detective Comics Vol 1.: Faces of Death which is a first trade in New52 Detective Comics line.